# Get current language in C#

Tags: localization, c1-cms

In Composite C1 I need to fetch the currently selected language, that the user selected over the [language switcher package](http://docs.composite.net/Packages/Navigation/CompositeNavigationLanguageSwitcher) in an ASP.NET user control.

Of course I could read it from the PathInfo, but I bet there is a function for this.

How can I access the value programmatically in C#?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pure vanilla c#

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx